# How can I retreive images from the shopify buy sdk (with a custom query)?

Tags: javascript, node.js, shopify, shopify-api, shopify-javascript-buy-sdk

I am simply trying to fetch products by tag with the [shopify buy sdk](https://github.com/Shopify/js-buy-sdk). Unfortunately this is not supported by the SDK by default, so I am forced to "build your own query".

I am able to fetch the products properly, with a few static fields, but fields that are arrays of other data types are not cooperating.

Here was my initial attempt:

```
        product.add('images', (image) => {
            image.add('src');
        });
```

I have tried many many variations, but they always end in an error, such as

- there is no field of name "src" found on type "ImageConnection" in schema
- there is no field of name "pageInfo" found on type "ImageEdge" in schema
- there is no field of name "pageInfo" found on type "Image" in schema
- connections must include the selections "pageInfo { hasNextPage, hasPreviousPage }".
- Parse error on "}" (RCURLY) at [1, 217] { line: 1, column: 217 }

here is my full code:

```
async function getProductsByTag (tag) {
    const productsQuery = client.graphQLClient.query((root) => {
        root.addConnection('products', { args: { first: 250, query: 'tag:'+tag } }, (product) => {
            product.add('title');
            product.add('handle');
            product.add('productType');
            product.add('images', (image) => {
                image.add('src');
            });
        });
    });
    let result = await client.graphQLClient.send(productsQuery);
    return result.data.products.edges.map(p => p.node);
}
```

This version seems more right, but still returns the `No field of name "pageInfo" found on type "ImageEdge" in schema` error.

```
        product.add('images', { args: { first: 250 } }, (imageConnection) => {
            imageConnection.addConnection('edges', { args: { first: 250 } }, (image) => {
                image.add('node', (node) => {
                    node.add('src');
                });
            });
        });
```